# How to get the unique value in autocomplete in php from mysqldatabase

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, autocomplete

How to get the unique value in autocomplete in php from mysqldatabase. and how do i get all values just like i have 3 values in autocomplete which same so i want only one in autocomplete but want to fetch the data of all. how do i do this ?

[image]

just like in picture i want 1 one php only but want the data from all the three values.
i am trying some thing like this

```
   var citycode;

      $('#countryname_1').autocomplete({
source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'ajax.php',
        dataType: "json",
        method: 'post',
        data: {
           name_startsWith: request.term,
           type: 'country_table',
           row_num : 1
        },
         success: function( data ) {

            response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                var code = item.split("|");
                    var len=code.length;
                    var co= code[0];



                return {
                    label: code[0],
                    value: code[0],
                    data : item


                }
            }));
        }
    });
},
autoFocus: true,            
minLength: 0,
select: function( event, ui ) {
    var names = ui.item.data.split("|").length; 
    var dat = ui.item.data.split("|");  
        citycode=dat[0] ;   
        alert(citycode);            
}
```

});